# Cones is smooth hypersurface

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

Let $H_c:=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n_{\nu} \vert <x,x>=c \}$. I want to proof the following statements:

1) $H_c$ is a pseudo-Riemannian hypersurface $\Leftrightarrow$ $c \neq 0$.

2) $H_0 \setminus \{0\}$ is a smooth hypersurface, but not a pseudo-Riemannian hypersurface.

3) The Weingarten map of $H_c$ with $\zeta(x)=x$ is $S^{\zeta}=-Id$

What I have so far:

1) I know that for some smooth $F \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n_{\nu})$ it holds that $F^{-1}(0)$ is a smooth manifold if $0$ is a regular value of $F$ (Though I am not sure if this is equivalent). 
Define 
$F(x):= \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\nu} -x_1^2 + \sum\limits_{j=\nu+1}^n x_j^2 -c$

Now $grad F=(-2x_1 ... -2x_{\nu} \ 2x_{\nu+1} ... 2x_n)^T$, so $F^{-1}(0)$ is a smooth manifold if $x \neq 0$ so $c \neq 0$.
Is that correct?

2)Now the first part follows with the same argumentation as above, but I'm not sure how to do the second part. I need to find some $v,w\neq 0 \in T_pH_c$, s.t. $g_p(v,w)=0$.

3) I need to show that $\zeta$ is a unit normal and that $-\nabla_X \zeta=-Id$ for all $X \in \mathfrak{X}(H_c)$ right? Now the second part is obvious, because $\nabla_X \zeta = \zeta(X)=X$, is that correct? And how to show the first part?

Thanks already in advance for any answers!

Comment: $H_0$ is not a smooth hypersurface. Take $n=3$ and $\nu =1$, you get the cone $x^2+y^2=z^2$ which is not smooth at the origin $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: Thanks for saying! I wanted to write $H_0 \setminus 0$!